# How to take simultaneous turns in Android Play Games Services Turn Based Multiplayer games?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm making a cooperative two-player turn based multiplayer game using Android Play Games Services Turn Based API. Each player submits a word and if they match, the game is over and they both win. If not, they each submit another word (somehow related to the previous two words) until they win.

So it's never really any one player's turn. They can each submit their guess at any time during the round. (i.e. either player can go first in a round). This doesn't seem to be how the turn based API works, though. It seems to require only one player to be active at a time, and hold the "state" hostage until they release it to the next player.

My question is: how can I achieve this style of gameplay using the Turn Based API? Is it possible for a player to "steal" the turn and go twice in a row, e.g.?

(I don't want to use the Realtime API because the game can go days without either player taking a turn)

Comment: it's probably possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out so that it'll still work with turn-based play. If you're curious, here's my solution:

Player 1 has the first turn. He submits a word and gives the turn over to player 2. Player 1's word is hidden from player 2 and player 2 receives a notification that it's his turn. There are two cases: Player 2 has already entered a word, or player 2 hasn't entered a word yet.

Case 1: Player 2 has already entered a word, so it's sent over to player 1 and player 2's turn ends.

Case 2: Without seeing player 1's word, player 2 enters a word, it's sent to player 1 and player 2's turn ends.

In either case, after sending his word over, player 2 is shown player 1's word and can proceed to enter the next word based on the two words from the previous round. Player 1 receives a notification that it's his turn, enters a second word and awaits player 2's response.